# Run code with cargo run on Raspberry Pi Pico using elf2uf2-rs

Tags: rust, embedded, rust-cargo, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I try to run Rust code on a Raspberry Pi Pico. A simple ["blink" example](https://github.com/rp-rs/rp-hal/blob/main/rp2040-hal/examples/blinky.rs) application is successfully (as it seems) built using:

```
cargo build --release --target=thumbv6m-none-eabi
```

I have installed [elf2uf2-rs](https://github.com/JoNil/elf2uf2-rs) with:

```
cargo install elf2uf2-rs
```

And I then try to run the blink application on the Raspberry Pi Pico using:

```
cargo run --release --target=thumbv6m-none-eabi
```

but it fails with this message, where "rp2" is the name of my binary:

```
target/thumbv6m-none-eabi/release/rp2: cannot execute binary file
```

Any suggestions on what can be wrong?

This is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "rp2"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rp2040-hal = "0.3.0"
cortex-m = "0.7.2"
embedded-hal = { version = "0.2.5", features = ["unproven"] }
eh1_0_alpha = { version="=1.0.0-alpha.6", package="embedded-hal", optional=true }
embedded-time = "0.12.0"
panic-halt = "0.2.0"
rp2040-boot2 = "0.2.0"
cortex-m-rt = "0.7"
rp-pico = "0.2.0"

[dev-dependencies]
cortex-m-rt = "0.7"
panic-halt = "0.2.0"
rp2040-boot2 = "0.2.0"

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

---

## Update

I now added a file `.cargo/config.toml` with this content:

```
# Choose a default "cargo run" tool.
# probe-run is recommended if you have a debugger
# elf2uf2-rs loads firmware over USB when the rp2040 is in boot mode
[target.'cfg(all(target_arch = "arm", target_os = "none"))']
# runner = "probe-run --chip RP2040"
runner = "elf2uf2-rs -d"

rustflags = [
    "-C", "linker=flip-link",
    "-C", "link-arg=--nmagic",
    "-C", "link-arg=-Tlink.x",
    "-C", "link-arg=-Tdefmt.x",

    # Code-size optimizations.
    #   trap unreachable can save a lot of space, but requires nightly compiler.
    #   uncomment the next line if you wish to enable it
    # "-Z", "trap-unreachable=no",
    "-C", "inline-threshold=5",
    "-C", "no-vectorize-loops",
]

[build]
target = "thumbv6m-none-eabi"
```

and a `memory.x` file with this content:

```
MEMORY {
    BOOT2 : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x100
    FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x10000100, LENGTH = 2048K - 0x100
    RAM   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 256K
}

EXTERN(BOOT2_FIRMWARE)

SECTIONS {
    /* ### Boot loader */
    .boot2 ORIGIN(BOOT2) :
    {
        KEEP(*(.boot2));
    } > BOOT2
} INSERT BEFORE .text;
```

but then the `cargo build --release` command fails with this error:

```
error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit status: 1
...
= note: rust-lld: error: cannot find linker script defmt.x
```

---

I use a MacBook with M1 Apple Silicon chip, this might be a related issue [rust-lld problem under AArch64 system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009533/rust-embedded-application-is-not-linked-correctly-under-aarch64-system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now got the code running on the Raspberry Pi Pico.

The first problem was that I hadn't created the `.cargo/config.toml` file that contains the instruction to "run" with elf2uf2:

```
[target.'cfg(all(target_arch = "arm", target_os = "none"))']
runner = "elf2uf2-rs -d"
```

The other problem was that my `.cargo/config.toml` also contained this reference to [defmt](https://defmt.ferrous-systems.com/) that I didn't have on my system, so when commenting out this line (under `rustflags`), the code compiled with `cargo build --release` and it was run on the Raspberry Pi Pico with `cargo run --release`:

```
# "-C", "link-arg=-Tdefmt.x",
```